# NG-Repeat won't update when array is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table created using AngularJs

```
<tr class="restTable" data-ng-repeat="tag in tags|orderBy: 'number'">
```

I use a filter (`<select>` tag). And the following function on it's change:

```
$scope.showTypeChange=function(){
        console.log($scope.showType);
        if($scope.showType==3){//all
            console.log($scope.tags);
            $scope.tags=tags;
            console.log($scope.tags);
        }
        tagsShow=[] 
        $scope.tags=tagsShow;//reset array
        var j=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            if(tags[i].type==$scope.showType){
               tagsShow[j]=tags[i];
               j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is if I use `showType==3` it doesn't show anything , even though on console `$scope.tags` result to be updated. In other cases everything works perfectly.

What do I miss?

Comment: can you make a fiddle fo this?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: well of course you are resetting  `$scope.tags` and never setting it again. Just do  `$scope.tags=tagsShow;` afterthe last `for` loop instead before it

Comment: can you add your code into jsfiddle.net

Comment: Damn I missed `else{}`, thanks guys... I should stop working during nights and do so silly errors....